# Decoding the encoded Pound symbol in java

Tags: java

we are using the external service to get the data in a CSV format. we are trying to write the data to response so that the csv can be downloadable to client. unfortunately, we are getting the data in the below format.

```
Amount inc. VAT      Balance
Â£112.83             Â£0.0
Â£97.55              Â£0.0
Â£15.28              Â£0.0
```

we are unable to decode the content. Is there a way to decode `Â£` and display `£` in java.

Is there any String Utils available to decode the strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:** 
when we use the getBytes() over string, it tries to decode using the default encoder. once the String is encoded, decoding may not work well if we use the default decoders.

**Solution: One**
StringUtils of apache will help us in decoding these characters while writing back to the response.
This class is available in `org.apache.commons.codec.binary` package.

```
String CSVContent = "/* CSV data */";
/**
 *  Decode the bytes using UTF8.  
 */
String decodedStr = StringUtils.newStringUtf8(CSVContent.getBytes("UTF-8"));
/**
 *  Convert the decoded string to Byte array to write to the stream  
 */
Byte [] content = StringUtils.getBytesIso8859_1(decodedStr);
```

Maven 2.0 dependency.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
     <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

**Solution: Two**

As per @Joni, Better solution with the standard API:

```
content = CSVContent.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: The same, shorter, with the standard API: `content = CSVContent.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");`

Comment: @Joni This is really best solution for my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The file seems to be encoded in UTF-8. You should read it as UTF-8.

If you are using `java.io.FileReader` and company, you should open a `FileInputStream` and use an `InputStreamReader` instead:

```
// Before: Reader in = new FileReader(file)
Reader in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8");
```

If you are using some other method for reading the file (an external or internal class library perhaps?), check in its documentation if it allows specifying the text encoding used to read the file.

**Update:** If you already have a String of mojibake like `Â£97.55` and cannot fix the way it is read, one way of recoding is by converting the string back into bytes and re-interpreting the bytes as UTF-8. This process does not require any external "StringUtils" or codec library; the Java standard API is powerful enough:

```
String input = ...obtain from somewhere...;
String output = new String(input.getBytes(/*use platform default*/), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: i tried to read the file from local machine, it worked well. But from the application it is not decoding properly.

Comment: @AnilKumarC What application do you mean? Probably the encoding of the input to this application is broken.

Comment: @AnilKumarC If you don't specify a character encoding when reading a file, the *default encoding* is used. The default encoding depends on the machine where you run the program, so you can expect to see different results on different systems.

Comment: In existing service they are prepending the £. while serealizing the data it is encoded to Â£. On the fly we need to decode and write the content back to response.

Answer (score 1):

We are lucky to have Java 7 now. You can do the following with [`Paths`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html), [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html), and [`StandardCharsets`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html):

```
Path path = Paths.get("/tmp", "input.txt");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
for (String line : lines) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```